# Circuit for safety button which turn off relay power supply

Tags: circuit-design

I have safety button with 2m of cable which is normal closed. When somone push safety button, circuit should turn off 5V_REL section. But there is some noise envoirment, and I do not want to 5V and 5V_REL on button. Additionally I need to detect disabling this voltage on 3.3V level and I need LED on 2m cable which indicates that 5V_REL is off.

What should I use for that circuit optocoupler? or just RC filters.
Using MOSFET for disconnect 5V_REL?

Comment: @jsotola edited

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: I do not understand "I do not want to 5V and 5V_REL on button." What does that mean?

Comment: The word ‘safety’ rings alarm bells. It sounds like you want to modify a safety circuit with something less safe. For safety systems like machine interlocks and motor emergency stops, there may be laws that dictate what you must do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: safety must be designed into the application and not added later. You simply can't graft on a safety circuit to a machine.

In safety the KISS principle rules, followed by redundancy, which is somewhat the total opposite.

If you put filters, isolators, whatever, you add failure points to the chain and the resiliency/reliability analysis becomes much more complex.

After that consider that mechanical is better than electromechanical that in turn is better than electronical. Software is almost forbidden except after extensive (and expensive certification). Safety in high power lasers is done with a *steel and concrete* block in the beam path, not a transistor switching the laser off (well, it is switched off, but it could fail and the shutter is the safety).

From what you tell your circuit is already at quite a low point of safety, since there is only one switch and only one relay: unless they are of exceptional quality (i.e. safety rated) if the switch breaks or one contact welds there would be no safety anymore. That's of course all depend of what that safety protect against. Without schematic and the risk analysis of the scenario it's difficult to say.

If you are worried about noise then better put a whole regulator dedicated to that line, it's cheap. Consider that a typical door interlock uses at least *three* guided contact relays (they cost 5-10 times more than the standard ones)